# sidekiq: deleted queues on sidekiq/queues page -- how to get them back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm birthing sidekiq queues via the Procfile:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q events -q summaries -c 5 -v
```

And in development I mistakenly deleted the queues events and summaries from the sidekiq/queues page.  I think they're still there and functioning but I can't SEE them.  I thought they would once again be added the minute I called the bundle exec sidekiq again but they're not there....

Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to push a job to them.  Queues don't actually exist in Redis unless they contain jobs.

Comment: I was -- well I thought I was; but I had changed the code from perform_later to perform_now in one section and it bypasses the queue apparently.